# how to switch user and pass password using paramiko

Tags: python, ssh

I am using a Python script which requires to have root access.

First I am becoming a  `normal` user, then I want to become `root`. But, `stdin.write` is still throwing error.

Here is my script:

```
import os
import paramiko
import subprocess

user="a554511"
p="xxxxxxx"
root="abcdefgh"
x="vljhggsajgfj"
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(x,username=user,password=p)
stdin.write('su -')

stdin.write("\n")
stdin.write(root)
stdin.flush()
stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh.exec_command('pwd')

x=stdout.readlines()

print(x)
ssh.close()
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paramiko-1.15.2-py2.6.egg/paramiko/file.py", line 339, in write
    self._write_all(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paramiko-1.15.2-py2.6.egg/paramiko/file.py", line 456, in _write_all
    count = self._write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paramiko-1.15.2-py2.6.egg/paramiko/channel.py", line 1220, in _write
    self.channel.sendall(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paramiko-1.15.2-py2.6.egg/paramiko/channel.py", line 744, in sendall
    sent = self.send(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paramiko-1.15.2-py2.6.egg/paramiko/channel.py", line 698, in send
    return self._send(s, m)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paramiko-1.15.2-py2.6.egg/paramiko/channel.py", line 1058, in _send
    raise socket.error('Socket is closed')
socket.error: Socket is closed
```

Comment: You are trying to write to STDIN... is that deliberate?

Comment: is that wrong? we use stdin to write only right?

Comment: If this is `sys.stdin`, then it is certainly wrong to write to it. However, the assignment (or importing) of the variable is not given in your code snippet, so I can't tell if it's a filehandle for reading or writing (or both).